# Else-if statement

Tags: java, methods

So I have my code working to tell me what the grade is for the average, however, what I need it to actually do is tell me what the grade is for each individual grade itself, example user enters for test1 80, I need it to say that the grade is a B and so on. This is what I have so far. Im not sure if I can even put multiple variables into 1 if else statement or not, or if Ill have to have 5 different else if statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;           //user input
import java.text.DecimalFormat;     //formats decimal places

/*This program is made to recieve 5 test grade inputs from the
user and then calculate their average and return their grade.
*/
public class Lab
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //place holders for test scores
      double test1,test2,test3,test4,test5;

      System.out.println("Enter 5 of your test grades: ");

      //create scanner for user imput
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      test1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      keyboard.nextLine();

      //calls method 1
      double average = calcAverage(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);

      //calls method 2
      getGrade(average);

      //formats how the average will be displayed
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
      System.out.println("The average is: " + df.format(average));
      System.exit(0);
   }

   /*
   The calcAverage method takes the test inputs from the
   user and divides them by 5 getting the average of all 5.
   */

   public static double calcAverage(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, double test5)  
   {
      double average = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5) / 5;
      return average;  
   }

   /*
   The getGrade method will take what was produced in the calcAverage method
   and find out where the average falls, thus giving the user his/her grade.
   */

   public static void getGrade(double average)
   {
      if (average>90)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have an A");  
      }  
      else if (average>=80)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a B");  
      }  
      else if (average>=70)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a C");  
      }  
      else if (average>=60)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a D");  
      }  
      else if (average<60)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a F");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the exact type of output?  EG "If I supply it with Example 82, I want it to output `Example's grade (82) is a B`".

Comment: instead of hard-coding `test{1-5}`, consider using a loop to handle each score in sequence.

Comment: Have you already learned arrays and loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getGrade()` should probably return the grade. Something like,

```
public static String getGrade(double average)
{
  if (average>90)  
  {  
    return "A";  
  }  
  else if (average>=80)  
  {  
    return "B";  
  }  
  else if (average>=70)  
  {  
    return "C";  
  }  
  else if (average>=60)  
  {  
    return "D";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    return "F";
  }
}
```

Then you call it for an individual test (or the average) -

```
System.out.printf("You got a %s on test1.", getGrade(test1));
```

Comment: @T.Woody That came from OP's post. Perhaps 91-100 is an A.

Comment: Thought I would ask :) Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: thank you I played around with what you gave me here and was able to get it to work! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `getGrade` on individual tests like shown below and rename the `getGrade` parameters name to `score` instead of `average` (this is just for readability)

```
import java.util.Scanner;           //user input
import java.text.DecimalFormat;     //formats decimal places

/*This program is made to recieve 5 test grade inputs from the
user and then calculate their average and return their grade.
*/
public class Lab
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //place holders for test scores
      double test1,test2,test3,test4,test5;

      System.out.println("Enter 5 of your test grades: ");

      //create scanner for user imput
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      test1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      test5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
      keyboard.nextLine();

      //calls method 1
      double average = calcAverage(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5);

      //calls method 2
      getGrade(average);

      // Gets grade for individual tests
      getGrade(test1);
      getGrade(test2);
      getGrade(test3);
      getGrade(test4);
      getGrade(test5);

      //formats how the average will be displayed
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
      System.out.println("The average is: " + df.format(average));
      System.exit(0);
   }

   /*
   The calcAverage method takes the test inputs from the
   user and divides them by 5 getting the average of all 5.
   */

   public static double calcAverage(double test1, double test2, double test3, double test4, double test5)  
   {
      double average = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5) / 5;
      return average;  
   }

   /*
   The getGrade method will take what was produced in the calcAverage method
   and find out where the average falls, thus giving the user his/her grade.
   */

   public static void getGrade(double score)
   {
      if (average>90)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have an A");  
      }  
      else if (average>=80)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a B");  
      }  
      else if (average>=70)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a C");  
      }  
      else if (average>=60)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a D");  
      }  
      else if (average<60)  
      {  
         System.out.println("You have a F");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put your tests into an `Array`:

```
double[] myTests = {test1, test2, test3, test4, test5};
```

and then iterate through:

```
for(int i=0; i<myTest.length; i++){
    getGrade(myTests[i]);
}
```

as for your `getGrade` method you might want to just return a `char` for each grade: A, B, C, ect and then only have one `System.out.print` statement. And my personal preference in a situation like this is to use a `switch-case` instead of `if-else`. Clearly this is school work though so I don't know what education level you are expected to code with

Comment: You have a typo. It's also more common to use `length` **property** instead of `size()` **method**.

Comment: Good call, it's been a while since I've used arrays ;)

Answer (score 0):

For some more OO design you can create a `Test` class and encapsulate the data within it:

```
public class Test
{
    public double Score;

    public String GetGrade()
    {
        if (this.Score > 90)  
        {  
            return "A";  
        }  
        else if (this.Score >= 80)  
        {  
            return "B";  
        }  
        else if (this.Score >=70)  
        {  
            return "C";  
        }  
        else if (this.Score >= 60)  
        {  
            return "D";  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            return "F";
        }
    }
}
```

I assume your question includes the instruction to just accept 5 test scores so we can use an array of size 5 (otherwise you could create an `ArrayList` and just add to it for each input):

```
Test[] tests = new Test[5];
```

Rather than accepting 5 inputs in a row, a better solution may be to print out the grade as each score is entered:

```
System.out.println("Enter test scores:");

//create scanner for user imput
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("Test %d: ", i + 1);
    tests[i].Score = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf("Grade is %s", tests[i].GetGrade());
}
```

Your calcAverage can then be more generic as well rather than hardcoding the number 5:

```
public static double calcAverage(Test[] tests)  
{
  double scoreSum;

  for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
  {
      scoreSum += tests[i].Score;
  }

  return scoreSum / test.length;  
}
```